# Convolutional Neural Network using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN model using Tensorflow, without the use of any frontend APIs such as Keras. I'm creating a VGG-16 model and using the pre-trained weights, and want to fine tune the last layers to serve my purpose.

Following the tutorial here, http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/training-convolutional-neural-network-for-image-classification/
I re-created the training script and modified as per my requirements. However, my training does not happen and the training accuracy is stuck at 50.00% and validation accuracy is forming a pattern repeating the numbers. 
Attached is the screenshot of the same. [image: terminal output of the training script]

I have been stuck on this for days now and can't seem to find the error. Any help is appreciated.

The code is pretty long and hence here is the [gist file](https://gist.github.com/abhijitnathwani/0d6bfc4805c722db25192ff0bc51924e) for the same

Answer (score 0):

Your cross entropy is wrong, you are comparing your logits with the softmax of your logits.

This:

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=layer_fc2,
                                                    labels=y_pred)
```

Should be:

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=layer_fc2,
                                                    labels=y_true)
```

Some things to note. I would not train on some data point and then evaluate on the same datapoint. Your training accuracy is probably going to be biased by doing so. Another point to note ist that `tf.argmax(tf.softmax(logits))` is the same as `tf.argmax(logits)`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did the change you suggested in `cross_entropy`. Still the the training accuracy is stuck at 50.00% and the validation acc forms a pattern repeating itself. Some other mistake in my code ?

Comment: please do have a look at it. @thomas-pinetz

Comment: What I do in cases like this is to look at the input and the output of my model. If the output of those tests matches the trained accuracy I will look at the gradients. Are they 0 or something spooky I would take a look at the loss function. It is hard for me to find errors in a code this long without being able to run it.

Comment: well i had a look at TensorBoard graph for the same. The layers do not seem to be connected. In the code, the output layer of 1 is the input layer of other. However, connections have not been made. Could spread some light on that?